# how do i output my related error in the string line

Tags: php, string

If I have a string line like `$text = '26061235+1234567,A1227011';`, 
I want to output the a string that is either shorter than 8 characters or contains non-numeric characters.

My expected output should be `1234567` and `A1227011`.

`1234567` because it is 7 characters long.
`A1227011` because it contains `A`.

This is the code I have written.

```
   $text = '26061235+1234567,A1227011';
   $splitted = preg_split('/[(or),\+]/', $text);

   $splitted = array_filter($splitted); // remove any empty string
   foreach($splitted as $str)
   {
       if(!is_numeric($str) || strlen($str)<=8)
       {
          $error=preg_replace('/\d+/','',$str);
          echo "this $error is not fine";
        }
   }
```

But i get no result in output

Comment: not up to 8 in lenght? Not sure I understand this correct. `A1227011` is 8

Comment: What is the delimiter? I see a plus and a comma both used as delimiters.

Comment: @Andreas As I read the question (I can be wrong, though) it's either numbers and less than 8 digits _or_ a string containing both a-z and 0-9.

Comment: not upto 8 in length or not a number

Comment: 12345678 is good and 1234567 is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!is_numeric($str) || strlen($str)<=8)
{
      $error=preg_replace('/\d+/','',$de);
      echo "this $error is not fine";
}
```

Why do you need `preg_replace('/\d+/','',$de);` here? Why not just:

```
if(!is_numeric($str) || strlen($str)<=8)
{
      echo $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '26061235+1234567,A1227011';
$splitted = preg_split('/[(or),+]/', $text);
$splitted = array_filter($splitted); // remove any empty string
foreach($splitted as $str)
   {

       if(!is_numeric($str) || strlen($str)<8)
       {
          $error=preg_replace('/d+/','',$str);
                echo "this $error is not fine<br/>";
        }
   }
```

Output :-

this 1234567 is not fine

this A1227011 is not fine